# Machine learning vehicle classification

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have folders containing images of cars that are front facing and rear facing. I want to know if I can automate a new set of folders with images that determines if the images are cars that are front facing or rear facing?

I tried coding and searching videos on youtube.

Comment: This question is too broad to be answered here. Consider researching machine learning frameworks like TensorFlow, PyTroch and how to manipulate directories on your OS using python.